# How to fix a segmentation fault for Ansi C Tcp client?

Tags: c, tcp, segmentation-fault, buffer

I'm trying to expand an example of a Tcp client developed using Ansi C, following the book "TCP/IP Sockets in C". The client connects to a Tcp Server providing strings of different lengths depending on the request provided by the client (I developed my own simple protocol). When the returned strings are short in length, everything works fine. When they're over a certain length (it happens for example with 4KB), the client crashes with a Segmentation Fault error.

The socket is handled using a wrapper to stream the i/o:

```
FILE *str = fdopen(sock, "r+"); // Wrap for stream I/O
```

And the transmission and reception are handled using fwrite() and fread().

This is the call that generates the error in my project (the caller):

```
uint8_t inbuf[MAX_WIRE_SIZE];
size_t respSize = GetNextMsg(str, inbuf, MAX_WIRE_SIZE); // Get the message
```

And this is the implementation of the GetNextMsg() function, that use to receive the data and unframe it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include "Practical.h"

/* Read 4-byte length and place in big-endian order.
 * Then read the indicated number of bytes.
 * If the input buffer is too small for the data, truncate to fit and
 * return the negation of the *indicated* length.  Thus a negative return
 * other than -1 indicates that the message was truncated.
 * (Ambiguity is possible only if the caller passes an empty buffer.)
 * Input stream is always left empty.
 */
uint32_t GetNextMsg(FILE *in, uint8_t *buf, size_t bufSize)
{
    uint32_t mSize = 0;
    uint32_t extra = 0;

    if (fread(&mSize, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, in) != 1)
        return -1;
    mSize = ntohl(mSize);
    if (mSize > bufSize)
    {
        extra = mSize - bufSize;
        mSize = bufSize; // Truncate
    }
    if (fread(buf, sizeof(uint8_t), mSize, in) != mSize)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Framing error: expected %d, read less\n", mSize);
        return -1;
    }
    if (extra > 0)
    { // Message was truncated
        uint32_t waste[BUFSIZE];
        fread(waste, sizeof(uint8_t), extra, in); // Try to flush the channel
        return -(mSize + extra);                  // Negation of indicated size
    }
    else
        return mSize;
}
```

I suspect that this could be related to the fact that with Tcp, sender and receiver are handling data with a streaming behavior, therefore it's not granted that the receiver
gets all of the data at once, as the simple example from which I started probably assumed. In fact, with short strings everything works. With longer strings, it doesn't.

I've done a simplified debug inserting a printf as a first thing inside of the function, but when I have the crash this doesn't even get printed.

It seems like an issue with the FILE *str passed as an argument to the function, when 
via the socket a message longer than usual is received.

The buffers are sized far bigger than the length of the message causing the issue (1MB vs 4KB).
I've even tried to increase the size of the socket buffer via the setsockopt:

```
int rcvBufferSize;
    // Retrieve and print the default buffer size
    int sockOptSize = sizeof(rcvBufferSize);
    if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvBufferSize, (socklen_t*)&sockOptSize) < 0)
        DieWithSystemMessage("getsockopt() failed");
    printf("Initial Receive Buffer Size: %d\n", rcvBufferSize);

    // Double the buffer size
    rcvBufferSize *= 10;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvBufferSize, 
sizeof(rcvBufferSize)) < 0)
        DieWithSystemMessage("setsockopt() failed");
```

but this didn't help.

Any ideas about the reason and how could I fix it?

Comment: Start by using a debugger to check when and where in your code the crash happens, sometimes debug printing isn't enough. Also when you catch the crash in a debugger you can examine variables and see their values when the crash happens, to make sure they're all okay.

Comment: One point that makes me curious though, why do your `GetNextMsg` function return a value of type `uint32_t` when you return negative values from the function? The compiler should complain about that (with high enough warning levels selected). Could that have something to do with the problem, that the returned value is "negative" (and on a normal computer will be really really big)? Also generally always enable high levels of warnings, as the compiler is often quite good at detecting things that could lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Hi, concerning the uint32_t, yes you're right. While adapting the example from the book (where the returned value was an int8_t, I got confused and used an unsigned instead, when updating to 32 bits). Concerning the debugger, you're totally right! I was assuming the issue to be on the GetNextMsg since no printf() after that function got printed, but  using the debugger I found out that the real issue was in the decoding function I used after the unframing: the parameter used to host the response from the server was too small, hence the memory violation and crash! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
 { // Message was truncated
    uint32_t waste[BUFSIZE];
    fread(waste, sizeof(uint8_t), extra, in); // Try to flush the channel
```

reads `extra` bytes into a buffer of size `4*BUFSIZE` (4 because you intended to make the buffer `unit8_t`, but accidentally made it `uint32_t` instead).

If `extra` is larger than `4*BUFSIZE`, then you will have a local buffer overflow and stack corruption, possibly resulting in a crash.

To do this correctly, something like this is needed:

```
  int remaining = extra;
  while (remaining > 0) {
    char waste[BUFSIZE];
    int to_read = min(BUFSIZE, remaining);
    int got = fread(waste, 1, to_read, in);
    if (got <= 0) break;
    remaining -= got;    
  }
```